# call_usr_func_array can't get magic method __call

Tags: php

Hello I created framework PHP, but i get problem when i used magic method `__call`. I called my controller using `call_usr_func_array` like this.

```
    $slice = [];
    if(count($segment)>2){
        $slice = array_slice($segment,2);
    }
    try{
        call_user_func_array([$controller,$m],$slice);
    } catch(\ArgumentCountError $e){
        throw new \ArgumentCountError("Segment tidak sesuai dengan controller");
    }
```

And my controller.

```
namespace Http\Controllers;

class ApiController{
    public function index(){
        echo json_encode(['status'=>200,'message'=>"Welcome to API Page"]);
    }
    public function __call($m,$p){
        dd($m);
    }
}
```

and i get this error. How to solve this error. Thank you.

[Error Result][1]

[image]

Comment: I guess you somewhere in the code typed randomly `ASDA`.

Comment: All works as expected: https://3v4l.org/Jgpi2

Comment: Please quote error messages verbatim inside your question in text form, don’t just show screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$controller needs to be an instance of the class, not a string, but in your screenshot, seems you assign $controller to be just a string with the class name, then you create an instance of that class... but don't save the instance anywhere. i guess you meant to write `$controller = new $controller;`, which would make $controller an object, which should make your call_user_func_array  call work.